# SWF not loading in ie8 after we switched to SSL

Tags: ssl, internet-explorer-8, https, flash, xml-swf-charts

We recently switched our webapp to use SSL at the request of a very large client. We complied and everything went smooth until my IE users started emailing support about not seeing our flash graphs (XML/SWF Charts: www.maani.us/xml_charts/)

In IE8 it prompts that insecure content is being delivered, we fixed this issue by changing the flash plugin links in the embed code to call https, but the swf's just have red X's in the upper left hand corners.

Browsing directly to the swf's has the same effect. Red X's like the content doesn't exist.

I have updated ie8's flash to 10.0.45.2

FF, Chrome, and Safari work just fine. IE7 will load the swf, but won't load the xml to power the graph. These graphs have worked for over two years without issue until the SSL/https switchover we completed over the weekend.

The embed code is here: https://gist.github.com/f425b370de390764bd75 links to screenshots are at the top of the gist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because of an issue with IE and headers.

Here are more links to the issue and the solution involves changing the headers you're sending.  This is not a fun bug to deal with.

**http://www.blog.lessrain.com/flash-loading-and-browser-cache-test-suite/**

**[How to prevent caching in Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234067)**

**[Load Method Fails to Load XML Documents over SSL Connection](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;272359)**

Comment: Thanks for the response David. I'll have to check these solutions out in the morning with my architecture engineers (they got me, the frontend guy, involved b/c its 'a flash problem')

Comment: Ok we removed all Cache-Control headers and it fixed the issue in IE7 and IE8. Specifically in haproxy: rspidel  Cache-control.

Thanks for pointing us in the right direction!

Comment: David...I think I love you.  In that deep, dark and bromantic sort of way that only a programmer who's been fighting with IE over its clandestine attempts to push me over the edge can.